# Editing Arules Data Frame in R

Tags: r, arules

Hi there I have transform my arules into data frame for further analysis but the problem is my data frame looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(rules=c("{45107} => {62557}","{17759} => {60521 }",
"{53721} => {53720}","{63830} => {17753}","{45413} => {45412}",
"{3885,59800,17759} => {4749}","{17721,55906} => {9314}"))

    rules
{45107} => {62557}
{17759} => {60521 }
{53721} => {53720}
{63830} => {17753}
{45413} => {45412}
{3885,59800,17759} => {4749}
{17721,55906} => {9314}
```

Can you help me change my data frame into this format?

```
lhs1    lhs2    lhs3    rhs
45107           62557
17759           60521
53721           53720
63830           17753
45413           45412
3885    59800   17759   4749
17721   55906   9314
```

Comment: @sayan dasgupta, I already transform my arules into data frame so my problem now is how can separate my column into multiple columns in data frame. The problem does not really have anything to do with a rules.

Comment: oops sorry yes; got it

Comment: Sorry to ask but I would think all numbers after `=>` would go to column `rhs` and all numbers before would be "dispatched" in the columns `lhs.` ?

Comment: @ CathG That's what I thought too when I change my arules into data frame but unfortunately it merge into 1 column called rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data.frame df and putting all numbers after `=>` in `rhs` :

```
# define the number of maximum "lhs", there is 2 options :
   # option 1, if there are few rules and number of maximum "lhs" is obvious :
maxlhs<-3
   # option 2, if there are many many rules and you don't want to count all "lhs" :
maxlhs<-max(sapply(df$rules,FUN=function(x)length(gregexpr(',',x)[[1]]))) + 1 

# create your new data.frame by "reformatting" the rules
newdf<-t(apply(df,1,function(rule,maxlhs){
                split1<-strsplit(gsub("[ }{]","",rule),"=>")[[1]]
                split2<-strsplit(split1[1],",")[[1]]
                split2<-c(split2,rep(NA,maxlhs-length(split2)))
                return(as.numeric(c(split2,split1[2])))
                    },maxlhs=maxlhs))
# name the new data.frame's columns
colnames(newdf)<-c(paste0("lhs",1:maxlhs),"rhs")

> newdf
      lhs1  lhs2  lhs3   rhs
[1,] 45107    NA    NA 62557
[2,] 17759    NA    NA 60521
[3,] 53721    NA    NA 53720
[4,] 63830    NA    NA 17753
[5,] 45413    NA    NA 45412
[6,]  3885 59800 17759  4749
[7,] 17721 55906    NA  9314
```

Is that ok or do you want the new data.frame to be exactly like the one displayed in your question ?

Comment: You need to determine that the max number of possible lhs variable is 3. here is hard coded

Comment: @sayandasgupta, yes you're right, I'll put that as a parameter, thanks !

Comment: use this `maxlhs <- max(sapply(df$rules,FUN=function(x)length(gregexpr(',',x)[[1]]))) + 1  `

Comment: @sayandasgupta, although it might not be necessary if there are only few rules, this can indeed be very useful in case of a crowd of them, so, again, you're right, I'll add the line and, again, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like this, which should be quite efficient.

```
library(splitstackshape)  ## for cSplit() and loads data.table package

dt <- data.table(
    do.call(rbind, strsplit(gsub("[{} ]", "", df$rules), "=>"))
)
cbind(cSplit(dt[, .(V1)], "V1", ","), dt[, .(V2)])

#     V1_1  V1_2  V1_3    V2
# 1: 45107    NA    NA 62557
# 2: 17759    NA    NA 60521
# 3: 53721    NA    NA 53720
# 4: 63830    NA    NA 17753
# 5: 45413    NA    NA 45412
# 6:  3885 59800 17759  4749
# 7: 17721 55906    NA  9314
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# your data
library(stringr)
data <- structure(list(rules = c("{45107} => {62557}", "{17759} => {60521 }", "{53721} =>     {53720}", "{63830} => {17753}", "{45413} => {45412}", "{3885,59800,17759} => {4749}", "{17721,55906} => {9314}")), .Names = "rules", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

# extract all numbers
lhs <- lapply(data, function(x) str_extract_all(x, "\\d+"))$rules
mx <- max(sapply(lhs, length))

do.call("rbind", lapply(lhs, function(x){
  if(length(x) < mx){
   return(c(unlist(x)[-length(x)], matrix(NA, 1, mx - length(x)), unlist(x)[length(x)]))
   } else {
   return(x)
}}))

     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
[1,] "45107" NA      NA      "62557"
[2,] "17759" NA      NA      "60521"
[3,] "53721" NA      NA      "53720"
[4,] "63830" NA      NA      "17753"
[5,] "45413" NA      NA      "45412"
[6,] "3885"  "59800" "17759" "4749" 
[7,] "17721" "55906" NA      "9314"
```